# Fast routine to change all but one 1 to 0 in each column of a matrix at random

Tags: r, optimization

I have a model that creates an n by m matrix ('mat') of zeros and ones that looks a bit like this :

```
n = 10
m = 1e3
p = 0.1
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix( as.numeric( ( p >= runif(n*m) ) ), nrow=n )
```

I'm trying to simulate some process. Basically, if any column contains more than one instance of 1, I want to change all the other 1s in that column to zeros. I want to allocate these at random.

I can do this:

```
funx <- function(x){
    ind <- which(x==1)
    n.ind <- length(ind)
    x <- rep(0,length(x))
    x[ind[sample.int(n.ind, 1)]] = 1 
    x
}

out <- sapply(1:m, function(ii){
        x <- mat[,ii]
        if ( sum(x) > 1  ) x <- funx(x)
        x})


mat[,1:10]
out[,1:10]
```

So columns 4,8 and 9 are correctly altered.

In practice, m is large say 2e6 and this is a bit slow. Is there a faster way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is significantly faster to do the replacements all at once via indexing rather than iterating over the columns.

```
funx <- function(m) {
  # Column indices of multiple 1s
  ci <- which(colSums(m) > 1)
  
  if (length(ci) > 0) {

  # Row indices of 1s to keep - using max.col (ties broken at random) on the transposed subsetted matrix
  ri <- max.col(t(m[, ci]))
  
  # Set all columns with multiple 1s to 0
  m[, ci] <- 0
  
  # Re-set single value to 1
  m[cbind(ri, ci)] <- 1
  }
  m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the main problems I found with your approach is that you are looping through all columns and performing the colSums operation inside the loop.

I think you may gain some performance if you perform colSums() before the loop, and then loop through only the subset of columns that satisfy the condition and replace these columns in place with your function.

Creating out2 matrix for comparison:

```
out2<-mat
```

First, create an index so you can loop through only the columns that satisfy the condition. `colSums()` is super fast.

```
index_of_cols<-colSums(out2)>1
```

Then, create a matrix to replace only the columns of interest

```
out_intermediate<-out2[, index_of_cols]
out_intermediate <- sapply(1:sum(index_of_cols), function(ii){
        x <- out_intermediate[,ii]
        funx(x)})
```

Finally, replace the columns of interest with the replacement out_intermediate

```
out2[,index_of_cols]<-out_intermediate
        
out2[,1:10]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    1    1    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

All in a single call:

```
mat_func<-function(mat){
        index_of_cols<-colSums(mat)>1
        funx <- function(x){
                ind <- which(x==1)
                n.ind <- length(ind)
                x <- rep(0,length(x))
                x[ind[sample.int(n.ind, 1)]] = 1 
                x
        }
        out_intermediate <- sapply(1:sum(index_of_cols), function(ii){
                x <- mat[,index_of_cols][,ii]
                funx(x)})
        mat[,index_of_cols]<-out_intermediate
        mat
}
```

For a new matrix created with the same parameters, but `m=2e6`:

```
> system.time(mat_func(mat))
   user  system elapsed 
  6.009   0.314   6.353 

# A modest 40% faster run time
```